# We have a linear mapping $T:C([0,1],\mathbb{R})\to C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with $Tf(t)=t^2f(t)$ and $C([0,1])$ has supremum norm.

Tags: normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Solve $||T||$ and show that with mapping $I:C([0,1],\mathbb{R})\to C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ where Ix=x we get that $||I+T||=1+||T||.$

I have managed to find the way of equation: $||T||=\sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{||Tf||}{||f||}=\sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|Tf(t)|}{\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|}$,
but don't know how to continue.

I have also managed to show:
$||I+T||\leq ||I||+||T||=\sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{||If||}{||f||}+||T|| = \sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{||f||}{||f||}+||T||=1+||T||$,
but that's only the difference and not the whole solution.

Comment: For your second question:  think about what the operator $I+T$ does in order to get the reverse inequality (i.e. if $f\in C([0,1])$, what does $(I+T)f$ look like?)

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is linear, note that
$||T||=\sup_{||f|| = 1}||Tf(t)||$.

Now, for $f$ to have norm $1$ means that its largest value is 1 (in absolute value). 
Now consider $Tf(t) = t^2f(t)$. Under the above constraint, it is clear that this is less than $1$. Therefore this gives an upper bound on the norm of $T$.

To see that this is actually the norm of $T$, consider the function $f(t) = 1$. Clearly this has norm $1$, and $Tf(1) = 1$, which gives you the lower bound of 1.

Comment: Thank you! My professor had done something similar in some of the examples but since he never explains what he is doing and skips some middle parts, it was so hard for me to understand what was happening there.